# How to make dynamic Query in SQL Server to my Scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

When I execute the following dynamic query, I got the result

```
[dbo].[spGetTotalSalesQuantity] @CustomerQuery=1,@DateFrom='2015-01-01 00:00:00',@DateTo='2015-12-31 23:59:59',@whereSql='tq.storeid=1001'
```

> **@whereSql='tq.storeid=1001'**  This is the important one

When I execute the following one it shows an error

```
[dbo].[spGetTotalSalesQuantity] @CustomerQuery=1,@DateFrom='2015-01-01 00:00:00',@DateTo='2015-12-31 23:59:59',@whereSql='tq.itemlookupcode=807424C0072'
```

> **@whereSql='tq.itemlookupcode=807424C0072'** in this part it shows an error. I should add the single quotation before and after the value.
>
> how can I add the single quotation before and after like this **tq.itemlookupcode='807424C0072'?**

this is the error msg

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'C0072'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply double time quotations will do the trick

```
@whereSql='tq.itemlookupcode=''807424C0072'''
```

Try below select

```
select 'tq.itemlookupcode=''807424C0072'''
```

You will get result like

```
tq.itemlookupcode='807424C0072'
```

Comment: Its ok :) @mohamedfaisal